# Call a function after a form is submitted using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to call a function after a form is submitted, I see we can do this in jQuery with `.submit(handler function())` but the method description says, the handler method will be executed just before the form is submitted. How can I actually attain this? Should I use `setTimeout` after the form is submitted or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You can't do something after the form is submitted, because that causes a new page to be opened, unless you use AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: Write your function on the target page.

Comment: bind event in `submit()`, submit the form yourself (using ajax) and then run what you wanted to execute after form submission

Comment: What do you want to do in that function?

Comment: I want to make an ajax call to a specific url while the Action class corresponding to this form is executing

Comment: u dont have to use any handler , simply call form.submit() when u want to submit it , just call your function , let it finish and then call form.submit , form== the reference to your form by id or by name

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#myFormId").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).prop('method'),
        url : $(this).prop('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        doYourStuff();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not calling the function "after" the form is submited

Comment: Not to mention that the submit might fail and you only want to execute MyfunctionCall() only if the submit was successful

Comment: Did'nt read the question well enough, but doing something after the form is submitted is only possible with ajax, and the form submit failing is'nt really part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use plugin http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit and do what ever you need on the callback method **success**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
    target:        '#output2',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 

    success:       function() {
                   // callback code here
                    }

}; 

// bind to the form's submit event 
$('#myForm2').submit(function() { 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

    return false; 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Flow:

1. window.sessionStorage['submit'] is initially an empty string.
2. once you type something in the textbox, and click the submit button, the value in the textbox is saved to window.sessionStorage['submit'].
   That means the window.sessionStorage['submit'] is not empty anymore. it containes a value.
3. the page refreshes after you submit the form.
4. the onload function will check if there is anything in window.sessionStorage['submit']. if its not empty it means that the form was submitted by a user.
   then it reset the window.sessionStorage['submit'] to empty string again.

Its using Session Storage which is supported in all the major browsers.

```
<html>
<body onload="checkSubmitStatus()">
<form name="text" action="">
<input type="text" id="txtId">
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="storeInSession()"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function storeInSession(){
    window.sessionStorage['submit'] = document.getElementById('txtId').value;
}

function checkSubmitStatus(){
    if(window.sessionStorage['submit']){
        alert('The form was submitted by '+ window.sessionStorage['submit']);
        window.sessionStorage['submit'] = '';
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get how this lets me know if the form is submitted.

Comment: thank you for the explanation let me try and see. If I am not able to achieve I have to go in for Barmer's suggestion of submitting the form via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the form submit event, then invoke the form submit manually and then execute your function..